# How to become an EOS Block Producer Candidate?

Tags: block-producer, voting

I've seen some conflicting info regarding on how one can become a Block Producer Candidate so that people can vote for me in the block producer votings. Some suggest that anyone can vote anyone they wish as long as they buy some resources in RAM, and the top 21 who receive the most number of votes become the Block Producers.

Then I've seen the official doc where there's a system command regproducer which supposedly registers an account to become a block producer (candidate) so others may vote for the account. While those accounts not registered with the command regproducer will not be able to receive a vote? But then it seems that anyone can run the regproducer command and register him/herself as a block producer candidate?

Lastly there's the EOSGO stuff which specifies that you need to have certain hardware resources, Steemit account, official website etc. etc. to become a Block Producer Candidate?

So what are exactly the requirements to become a block producer candidate in EOS so that others may vote for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official docs are correct: to become a BP candidate you just run

```
$ cleos system regproducer <account> <key>
```

and people can vote for you using their staked tokens as follows:

```
$ cleos system voteproducer prods <from> <for>
```

> Lastly there's the EOSGO stuff which specifies that you need to have certain hardware resources, Steemit account, official website etc. etc. to become a Block Producer Candidate?

These are just their recommended practices for what they believe BPs should have.